# Shape Integrity Error using GeoPackage in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geopackage, united-kingdom

I'm trying to use the OS Zoomstack dataset in ArcGIS Pro 2.9. It is in GeoPackage format. However, it doesn't display all the features (I've tried in QGIS which displays them all fine) and when I open the attribute table I get this error. I can't repair geometries in ArcGIS Pro as I receive an error, presumably because repairing geometries on GeoPackage files isn't supported. I get the same in ArcMap too.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the OS to verify that their geopackage does not contain any geometry errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the GeoPackage with this GDAL sample script https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/validate_gpkg.py. It will require some time to validate the 12 GB GeoPackage. Usage:

```
python validate_gpkg.py OS_Open_Zoomstack.gpkg
```

The script is running all the tests that are defined in the GeoPackage standard. If it does not report errors it is presumable that the GeoPackage is valid. Notice that if there are no errors then the script will not print any output at all!

If the Zoomstack file is valid I suggest to contact your local ESRI support channel and report the issue.

I just validated OS Zoomstack file that was downloaded in mid-October, no errors found.